# Uninstall multiple version of python3 on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, uninstall, python3

I've switched on Ubuntu 20.04 some days ago, and i wanted to install the latest version of python (3.8.5 at the time). The problem is that i've certainly not installed it properly and now i have two instance of python3. The default one which is working fine and the one i've installed which do not work fine (pip not working and cannot import lib like numpy,pyplot,...)

So i tried to remove by doing a `sudo apt remove python3.8.5` in the terminal, but it want uninstall a lot of programm which i dont want to install (virt-manager, ...).

Is there a way to remove all the installations that i have done and just keep the default python3 ?

And if possible, is there a way t update the default python to the latest version of python (3.9 currently) ?

Best regards chichha

Comment: Python 3.8.5 is the default version on amd64 architecture - are you using another platform? On my RasPi 4 (arm64), this is also the package version installed. So I don't understand why this wouldn't be the default version for you. [Package info](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3.8)

Answer (score 0):

Lot of system programs depend on python. Therefore tinkering with the system python can break your system. Easiest way is to install python from source or use Anaconda/Miniconda.

To install from source, install these packages:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

Then go to the download folder of python and

```
cd Python-3.8.5
./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=$HOME/local
make
make install
```

then append these lines to $HOME/.bashrc

```bsh
export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Reference: [towardsdatascience.com - Sushrut Ashtikar](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-python-from-source-on-ubuntu-20-04-2ed29eec152b)

Comment: In fact i do not have problem for install python. I want to uninstall certain version of python that i have installed. (because i got multiple python versions installed :3.8.2,3.8.5, 3.9))

Comment: If you have installed them using ```apt```, you can uninstall them using ```apt```. But many system services depend on python so uninstalling python is a bit risky. There may be two ways. Either you know the default version of python that was there before installing different versions, or you try to uninstall each version and see which of them uninstalls without any dependency. Through the latter way can get rid of unnecessary pythons easily.

Comment: Risk free way: keep the system pythons as it is and create a bash ```alias``` to the python version of your choice.